# ActiveRecord ignores "includes" when I order against one of two included associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following model (simplified):

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :priority
end
```

I am trying to load all jobs at once into a table that displays both the customer and priority, so I am eager loading both associations to avoid N+1 queries:

```
Job.includes(:customer, :priority)
```

So far so good. The problem comes when I want to order by customer name. Following Rails 4 instructions, I do this:

```
Job.includes(:customer, :priority).order("customers.name ASC")
```

**ActiveRecord stops eager loading priorities!** Rendering the table results in a separate query for each priority.

As a side note, AR is doing the join automatically without ".references(:customers)". This seems contrary to the documentation.